# apply function over multindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similiar to the following

```
data = {'lat': [90,80,70],'long':[100,110,100],'temp1':[[4,3,1,1],[6,2,3,-1],[1,2,3,4]],'temp2':[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[9,9,1,3]]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df3 = df3.set_index(['lat','long'])
```

I want to calculate the correlation between "temp1" and "temp2" for each multindex row, for that, I've defined the following function and used the apply method:

```
def corr_row(row):
    serie1 = row['temp1']
    serie2 = row['temp2']
    correlation = np.corrcoef(serie1,serie2)
    return correlation

df3["corr"] = df3.apply(corr_row)
```

but I get the error:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

I've managed to use the apply method in dataframes with one index, how should I use it in this case?

Comment: Try, `df3["corr"] = df3.apply(corr_row, axis=1)`

Comment: I did it and I get ``` No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>```, following previous questions I tried  with axis = 'index' or 'column'. None of them work

Comment: Move the `setting_index` line (`df3 = df3.set_index(['lat','long'])`) to the very end. Use `df3["corr"] = df3.apply(corr_row, axis=1)` before you set the index.